# $G$-structure of a product manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

My question concerns  [$G$-structures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-structure) on manifolds:

Let $M$ be an $n$-dimensional manifold. Since any $n$-dimensional manifold admits a riemannian metric, $M$ admits an $O_n$-structure.

Similarly, $\mathbb R \times M$, being an $n+1$-dimensional manifold, admits an $O_{n+1}$-structure.

My question is, since $\mathbb R$ is parallelizable and thus admits a trivial structure, is it valid to say that $\mathbb R \times M$ admits also an $O_n$-structure, where we view $O_n \subset O_{n+1}$?

In this case, thinking of $O_n \subset O_{n+1}$ by $\{g \in O_{n+1}: g =\textrm{diag}(1,h)  \textrm{ for some } h\in O_n\}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You may use sections of $O(n)$ structure on $M$ and paralelization of $\mathbb{R}$ to define sections of an $O(n)$ structure on $\mathbb{R} \times M$.